# Matlab Pde Toolbox: Plot solution on a line or on a submanifold

Tags: pde, matlab

I'm using the Matlab pde toolbox to solve a certain elliptic equation in 2D.

Solution is fine, although I do need to plot it along a given line, i.e. to cut a planar slice from the 3D mesh representing the solution.

I can't figure out a way that smartly involves the toolbox functions (i.e. not involving low level interpolation on the triangular mesh).

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I posted the same question on [MATLAB central](http://www.mathworks.it/matlabcentral/), and [Bill Greene](http://www.mathworks.it/matlabcentral/answers/contributors/2963969-bill-greene) kindly provided an [answer](http://www.mathworks.it/matlabcentral/answers/52403-plot-solution-of-pde-toolbox-on-a-line-or-submanifold).

I briefly report and extend it so that it can be useful to others.

Solution by Bill:

> Here is one way to create such a plot. Assume you have the point matrix created by the PDE Toolbox mesher, p, and a solution vector, u. The function below will create a plot of that solution along a line defined by the x and y locations of the two end points. My example is for a solution on a unit square and I want a plot along the line (0,.5) to (1,.5). I want to include 25 points in the plot. As you can see, the real work is being done by the **`TriScatteredInterp`** function from core MATLAB.
>
> ```
> plotAlongLine(p, u, [0,.5], [1,.5], 25);
>
> function plotAlongLine(p, u, xy1, xy2, numpts)
>     x = linspace(xy1(1),xy2(1),numpts);
>     y = linspace(xy1(2),xy2(2),numpts);
>     F = TriScatteredInterp(p(1,:)', p(2,:)', u);
>     uxy = F(x,y);
>     figure; plot(x, uxy);  //REM: x is chosen here as a curvilinear coordinate
> end
> ```

I'd like to further remark that the previous function allows one to plot the solution `u` or its functions `f(u)`, provided `u` is defined on mesh nodes (as typically happens for FEM approximated solutions).

If one needs to plot sections of functions defined on mesh centers (e.g. functions of `grad u`), she may use in advance the function `pdeprtni` which produces *node-valued-functions* out of *center-valued-functions*.